# Convert pipe delimited csv to tab delimited using batch script

Tags: postgresql, batch-file

I am trying to write a batch script that will query a Postgres database and output the results to a csv. Currently, it queries the database and saves the output as a pipe delimited csv.

I want the output to be tab delimited rather than pipe delimited, since I will eventually be importing the csv into Access. Does anyone know how this can be achieved?

Current code:

```
cd C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.1\bin
psql -c "SELECT * from jivedw_day;" -U postgres -A -o sample.csv cscanalytics
```

postgres = username
cscanalytics = database

Answer (score 4):

You should be using [COPY](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html) to dump CSV:

```
psql -c "copy jivedw_day to stdout csv delimiter E'\t'" -o sample.csv -U postgres -d csvanalytics
```

The `delimiter E'\t'` part will get you your output with tabs instead of commas as the delimiter. There are other other options as well, please see [the documentation](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-copy.html) for further details.

Using [`-A` like you are](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html) just dumps the usual interactive output to `sample.csv` without the normal padding to making the columns line up, that's why you're seeing the pipes:

> -A
>   --no-align
>   Switches to unaligned output mode. (The default output mode is otherwise aligned.)